# Can't figure out a way to produce an error if user hits Enter without giving an input

Tags: c++, xcode, error-handling, getline

Alright so I have to make a program that calculates monthly data bill.
The only thing I am stuck on is I can't get it to give an error if the user clicks enter without typing anything. I tried using get line() but I can't seem to make it read the char. Also how would I be able to produce an error because I think I'm doing something wrong.

I also keep getting no matching function for call to 'getline'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// State the different plans
cout << "A - $29.99 per month with 5000 megabytes.\n";
cout << "    $0.05 per additional megabyte, but only\n";
cout << "    $0.03 per additional megabyte if 50% or\n";
cout << "    more of the data was used on weekends\n";
cout << "B - $39.99 per month with 7500 megabytes.\n";
cout << "    $0.01 per additional megabyte\n";
cout << "C - $49.99 per month for unlimited megabytes.\n";

// Ask what plan the customer bought
cout << "Enter A, B, or C to chose the plan the user has purchased: ";
char input;

getline(cin, input);

// Capitalize the input
input = toupper(input);


// Ignore anything after the first letter
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use `std::getline()` is by having its second parameter be a `std::string`.

```
std::string input;

getline(cin, input);

if (input.size() == 0)
{
    // Nothing was typed in before hitting Enter.
}
```

This is much simpler than using `operator>>`, and then have to deal with `ignore()`, and other headaches, etc...

Comment: Yes but it is part of my assignment to use all what I have learned in class. Therefore I'm just trying to find a way to make this code work while still using these concepts.

Comment: You should've made that clear in your question. If you still want to use character-by-character input, just use `get()`, to read typed in input, one character at a time. If the first character read was '\n', the input is empty.

Comment: Okay I can try that, but how do I make it produce an error message if the user doesn't input anything?

Comment: I explained how in my last comment.

Comment: @MohamedElmalah `std::cout << "Hey! Need some input here!\n";` might work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used cin.getline in the following manner:

char str[64];
cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));

str will capture all characters entered until the return key. If the user simply hits return, str[0] will be set to 0, making str a 0 length string, strlen(str) will be 0.